# Elasticsearch Facets: Search on _index returned no results

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, facet

I want to search data on ES in this order by index-> by index_type-> text search data.
When I'am using the below query on "_index" I expected to get list of index_types under that particular _index and also the related data but it returned nothing. On the other hand when I searched by _type I got the data pertaining to the index_type. Where have I gone wrong?

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_all/_search?pretty' -d '{
      "facets": {
        "terms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "_index",
            "size": 10,
            "order": "count",
            "exclude": []
          },
          "facet_filter": {
            "fquery": {
              "query": {
                "filtered": {
                  "query": {
                    "bool": {
                      "should": [
                        {
                          "query_string": {
                            "query": "*"
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  "filter": {
                    "bool": {
                      "must": [
                        {
                          "terms": {
                            "_index": [
                              "<index_name>"
                            ]
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "size": 0
    }'
```

Note: I faced this problem first on Kibana, where I used the filter "_index":"name_of_index"; it returned no results but "_type":"name_of_index_type" returned the expected result. I found Kibana uses the above query behind the scenes to get the results of the filter I tried.

Comment: why you don't specify your index in the url ? 
use "aggs" (aggregations) because facets are depreciated .

Answer (score 0):

this is an example of query with pre filter  ( "query" : "*" ) and then a must&mustnot query. then the resutlt is used to make the aggregations :

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/YOUR_INDEX_NAME/_search?size=10' -d '{
    "query" : {
        "filtered" : {
            "query" : {
                "query_string" : {
                    "query" : "*"
                }
            },
            "filter" : {
                 "bool" : {
                    "must" : [
                        { "term" : { "E_RECORDEDBY" : "malençon, g."} },
                        { "term" : { "T_SCIENTIFICNAME" : "peniophora incarnata"  } }
                    ],
                   "must_not" : [
                     {"term" : {    "L_CONTINENT" : "africa"    } },
                     {"term" : {    "L_CONTINENT" : "europe"    } }
                   ]
             }
            }
        }
    },   
    "aggs" : {
        "L_CONTINENT" : {
            "terms" : {
                "field" : "L_CONTINENT",
                "size" : 20
            }
        }
    },
    "sort" : "_score"
}'
```